# Safe ways to retain an encryption key in a local service memory after a reboot?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, encryption, reboot

I'm writing a Windows service that receives an encryption key from our web server. Such key never leaves memory and is used to encrypt and decrypt sensitive data. This works well, except for the situation when the system is rebooted. In that case, the network is not yet available (it needs to be authenticated first) thus my service cannot connect to the server yet, but it still needs to obtain the encryption key.

Thus I was wondering if there is a way to safely retain the encryption key in memory after the system is rebooted (without saving it to disk in plaintext, which will expose it)?

Comment: If it where retained in memory across reboots than that would be as bad as having it on disk. It actually is retained across reboots if you know where to look unless your app purposefully overwrites it and prevents it from ever being swapped out. Windows will overwrite it before it lets any app read the memory though.

Comment: Can you not wait until the network is available and then acquire the key once it is?

Comment: try the `Securestring` mechanism to encrypt and protect sensitive data in RAM..
crypto libraries `crypto++` or `botan`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002951/win32-cryptprotectdata-method/71003103#71003103) help?

Comment: Why not simply encrypt the last known web key with a private key known only to the service, and then save the encrypted key in the Registry? The service can then retrieve and decrypt it, until a new web key can be obtained.

Comment: An important detail is who you are trying to protect the key **from**.  Are you worried about protecting it from administrators? From standard users? From somebody who steals the hard drive? You say that saving it to disk in plaintext will expose it, but who are you worried about exposing it **to**? (Because you can use ACLs to control who can see the plaintext data.)

Comment: @NathanOliver: the whole catch-22 is that no, I can't. To authenticate the network I need some of the sensitive data, which I can't decrypt without the key that I need to get from the server. But I can't connect to the server because the network is down.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, using `CryptProtectData`, or newer `NCryptProtectSecret` like SoronelHaetir suggested in his answer, could be a way to do it. Not the best one, but a workaround. (See my further reply.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau sure, except that private key is what I'm asking about here. How will my service have that private key upon boot? I'm not storing anywhere on disk, it is only kept in memory. I get that private key from the server, which is not available upon boot. Thus my question - how to pass that private key from memory into memory after a reboot.

Comment: I was thinking to use TPM, but I don't know if it supports such functionality, or if it's even feasible for what I need it for.

Comment: @RaymondChen good question. I obviously can't protect it from the administrators, as they can just read the memory from my service and obtain the key that is stored in it. This protection is from anyone else. The reason I didn't want to save the key on disk for the moment while system reboots is because it is trivial to "steal" it from there - shut down the system, take out the disk, plug it into the Linux system, read it and here you go. None of the NTFS permissions will stop them. Thus I have to use encryption to protect it.

Comment: If you want to protect against hard drive extraction, then use BitLocker to encrypt the hard drive. Encrypting it with a key hard-coded into your service is not sufficient because somebody can just reverse-engineer your service to extract the key.

Comment: @RaymondChen no, it's not hardcoded. As I said above the key is received from a web server and is never stored anywhere but in the service memory.  As for BitLocker, I cannot modify the end-user's major global setting just because my service is installed. So I need to find a different workaround.

Comment: @c00000fd I was referring to using a *different* private key, known only to the service, to encrypt the key provided by the server when saving it. You could hard-code that key in the service's code, though like Raymond said, it could be reverse-engineered. In my company's old apps, we wrote an algorithm that runs at runtime to produce a static key dynamically so it is not hard-coded in the code. No less subseptible to reverse-engineering, but requires more work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using NCryptRegisterProtectionDescriptorName  / NCryptCreateProtectionDescriptor along with NCryptProtectSecret/NCryptUnprotectSecret?

This is very similar to Remy Lebeau 's suggestion, only using already-existing windows API services. It won't be "in memory" (as memory is lost between boots) but does provide a should-be-secure means of storing such data.

Comment: I was thinking to use this approach too. Thus if I call `NCryptProtectSecret` on my secret key and save the result in registry before the boot, and then after the boot if I call `NCryptUnprotectSecret` to read it back into memory, and then delete it from registry - will the key be exposed on disk, say, if someone were to take the drive out and to read it in Linux. How easy will it be for them to get that key in that situation?

Comment: I'm not certain but I believe the machine key is recoverable so it would, in theory at least, be possible for someone with such access to recover the encrypted data (by first recovering the machine key and then using that key to decrypt the saved data). But also keep in mind that once someone has unlimited physical access to the hardware that most security is shot anyway. Security against what goes over the wire is a very different matter from security against hardware snooping.